# Call to API with different arguments returns the same data each time

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to put together a pandas dataframe for a school project with but to do so I am hitting an api repeatedly. I can't figure out excatly why I am returning the same dataframe over and over, sans the column title, any help much appreciated.

Code is as follows:

a.py

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


tmp = [] 
tmp_1 = []
def fetchdata(ticker):
    url = 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/'
    time = '/chart/5y'
    get = url + ticker + time
    data = requests.get(get).json()
    length = len(data)
    # i = i + 1
    for j in range(0, length):
        date = data[j]['date']
        closing = data[j]['close']
        x = tmp.append(date)
        y = tmp_1.append(closing)
        df = pd.DataFrame(x)
        df[ticker] = tmp_1
        df_1 = df.loc[1:1000]
    return df_1
```

b.py

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from slizzy import fetchdata

df_appl_1 = fetchdata('aapl')
df_appl_2 = fetchdata('aapl')
df_appl_3 = fetchdata('aapl')
df_gold = fetchdata('gld')

print df_appl_1
print df_gold
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your list declarations into your function:

```
def fetchdata(ticker):
    tmp = [] 
    tmp_1 = []
```

As it stands, after the first call to your function, these lists are not cleared out (because they're globals), so you successively query the same 1000 elements each time.